# Using jquery masonry with fluid full width grid

Tags: jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

I am struggling to force Masonry to properly position the elements of the boostrap's full width grid. 
As you will see home page is using the container with fixed width of the elements and everything is working as expected. But on the other hand, news page is using the full width fluid system and for some reason ,,blocks" on the news page won't fit the window.

Here is my call for masonry:

```
self.$("#masonry").masonry({
itemSelector: '.parallax',
isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions,
columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
return containerWidth / 6;
});
```

And here is an example link http://wheniamplaying.com/kitchenV3/en/home

Is it possible to use masonry in this scenario?